# Validating entity manager in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have a method for validating that my entity manager is valid. However at certain intervals the calls will stop returning data. If queried with the same sql into DB query window it will return the expected records.

Am I missing some kind of validation to make sure that it's actually valid?

```
private void validateEntityManager() {
        try {
            if (em == null || !em.isOpen())
                em = factory.createEntityManager();
            if (!em.isOpen() || !em.isJoinedToTransaction()) {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
            }
        } catch (javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException ex) {
            recreateEM();
        }

    }

private void recreateEM() {
    try {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Database error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Method returning data

```
public List<T[]> selectNativeQuery(String sql) {
        validateEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        List<T[]> listObj = query.getResultList();
        return listObj;
    }
```

Closing of the entity manager

```
public void saveToDatabase(T obj) {

        // select(obj);
        validateEntityManager();
        try {
            em.persist(obj);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        } catch (RollbackException | DatabaseException | javax.persistence.EntityExistsException e) {
            logger.debug(obj.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to execute transaction: " + obj.toString() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you close the transaction?

Comment: If I save I close at the end.